# How to establish routing between two interfaces in VyOS

Tags: networking, virtualbox, firewall

With this network setup and VyOS settings, the `10.0.0.10` windows machine is able to ping both sides of the VyOS router (`10.0.0.1` and `192.168.7.77`), but not the gateway (`192.168.7.254`). Therefore, my host `10.0.0.10` has no Internet access.

I believe this is a routing problem and I read in another [answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25364/vyatta-static-routing-between-2-lan) that routing between LANs should be auto. Routing table looks good to me as well.

```
vyos@vyos:~$ ip route show
default via 192.168.7.254 dev eth0  proto zebra
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.1
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1
192.168.7.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.7.77
```

Config:

```
interfaces {
    ethernet eth0 {
        address dhcp
        description unsafe
        duplex auto
        hw-id 08:00:27:20:e9:f9
        smp_affinity auto
        speed auto
    }
    ethernet eth1 {
        address 10.0.0.1/24
        description safe
        hw-id 08:00:27:e2:28:0a
    }
    loopback lo {
    }
}
service {
    dhcp-server {
        shared-network-name lab {
            authoritative enable
            subnet 10.0.0.0/24 {
                default-router 10.0.0.1
                dns-server 8.8.8.8
                start 10.0.0.10 {
                    stop 10.0.0.100
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ssh {
        port 22
    }
}
system {
    config-management {
        commit-revisions 20
    }
    console {
        device ttyS0 {
            speed 9600
        }
    }
    host-name vyos
    login {
        user vyos {
            authentication {
                encrypted-password ****************
                plaintext-password ****************
            }
            level admin
        }
    }
    ntp {
        server 0.pool.ntp.org {
        }
        server 1.pool.ntp.org {
        }
        server 2.pool.ntp.org {
        }
    }
    package {
        auto-sync 1
        repository community {
            components main
            distribution helium
            password ****************
            url http://packages.vyos.net/vyos
            username ""
        }
    }
    syslog {
        global {
            facility all {
                level notice
            }
            facility protocols {
                level debug
            }
        }
    }
    time-zone UTC
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As part of our troubleshooting we tried to ping another PC, a host at `192.168.7.68` instead of the gateway.

We found the issue was that the computer we were testing with on the `192.168.7.0/24` subnet did not have an entry in it's routing table for where to reply to the pings. We added a route to send packets for `10.0.0.0/24` back to `192.168.7.77` and pings were fine.

As we don't control the `192.168.7.254` gateway, and don't have a great way to know if it'll accept routes from `RIP` or `OSPF`, we settled for `NAT` and things worked out great.

Now the `192.168.7.0/24` hosts just reply to another PC on that network (`192.168.7.77`) and it translates back and forth. Obviously we'll need to forward ports if we want traffic to be able to originate from the `192.168.7.0/24` to the `10.0.0.0/24` network.